# ASP.NET Core Web API with Angular Frontend, using Azure AD for Authentication/Authorization

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I've done a ton of reading on this and I think I'm heading down the right path, I'm just looking for a sanity check on this. I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API and an Angular 6 frontend. I want to require logging into Azure AD before the user is able to access the application. I have the API working but I'm having a hard time understanding the process of how the Angular piece will come in. I know there's some IDP options like IdentityServer4 but isn't Azure AD providing this service? How do I make the Angular app redirect to Azure to sign in then store the authentication to pass into the API? Or is it more implicit on the Angular side where it's the API getting authenticated and just saying "he's with me" towards the Angular app?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [text.](http://www.digital-moves.eu/2018/07/19/authentication-with-azure-ad-angular-6-client-web-api/) Maybe there you will find something that will help you.